# Can I encrypt contents generated by an app?

Tags: encryption, hide

I installed a Digital Diary app from MS store yesterday and tried writing a demo entry to save it. When I investigated where the content is stored, I came to know that the entries were stored in a folder named `DigitalDiary` inside `Videos` folder in `C:\` drive. The entry that I make each day were saved separately in a file in `.dgd` format, but when I opened those files in notepad, I could see everything that I wrote in plain text.

Apparently, the contents were not `hashed` or `encrypted` and were stored as such. So, is there a way to stop people from accessing that particular folder called `DigitalDiary` and still being able to continue writing through the digital diary app?

I tried hiding the folder by going to properties but that gave an "Access Denied!" error in the app.

Comment: Are you saying that the content is not stored somewhere in the user's profile folder (i.e. C:\Users\yourname\), but in C:\Videos\DigitalDiary? Because that would be bad practise. What happens if another user logs into the same pc, and uses this app, does he/she see your content? Is his/her content stored in the same folder?

Comment: @Berend, yes it's stored in C:\Videos\DigitalDiary. Another user can't log in to the app since I have set a passcode there. But that another person can just go to C:\Videos\DigitalDiary and open the contents via notepad to see everything that I write in plain text :( It's like putting a gate in front of your house while keeping your backyard open for all :|

Comment: Then it looks like this app isn't designed with multi-user access in mind ;-) I'd stay away from it

Comment: Yes. Seems so!!